# Почему при нажати не ссылку одного URL открывается другой URL

Tags: php, laravel

***web.php***

```
Route::get('/callcar', function () {
    return view('callcar');
});

Route::get('/callcar', 'CallController@index')->name('callcar');
```

***сама ссылка***

```
<a class="btn btn-primary"  style="margin-bottom: 40px"  href="{{ route('callcar') }}">{{ __('Вызвать травнспорт') }}</a>
```

***CallController.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\applic;
class CallController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

        return view('callcar');

    }
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
```

> Сама проблема в том что когда нажимаю на ссылку которая должна вывести
>   URL (callcar) открывается URL (home) в чем проблема господа????.

Comment: Покажите route полностью

Answer (score 2):

У вас должен быть один роут в web.php из-за того что у вас два одинаковых, может происходить конфликт.

```
Route::get('callcar', 'CallController@index')->name('callcar');
```

Comment: Все равно перекидывает не на тот URL

Comment: Вы также не учли, что используется посредник `guest`, в котором и происходит переадресация на *home*, если пользователь аутентифицирован.

Answer (score 0):

Вы начнете видеть разницу между запросами GET и POST при отправке пар ключ / значение.

За дополнительной информацией:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods.htm